# Python: how to save different .csv for each ID in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like the following:

```
df
    ID    val
0    A     3
1    A     2
2    B     0
3    B     5 
4    B     4
```

I would like to save different dataframes for each users. This is what I am doing

```
for i in pd.unique(df['ID']):
      tmp = df[df['ID']==i]
      tmp.to_csv('%s.csv'%i)
```

However I have a very large dataframe and 14k ID. I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is good, here is alternative:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('ID', sort=False):
    g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), index=False)
```

Or solution with `f-string`s:

```
for i, g in df.groupby('ID', sort=False):
    g.to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=False)
```